# message when navigating away with an unsaved edit

Tags: discussion, navigation

[image]

Everytime I see this message, it makes my brain think...because I automatically read it as "You have started writing or editing a post. Press OK to continue..." and it puts me in the mode of "OK to continue writing or editing this post" (e.g. continue staying on the page, instead of continuing with navigating away from the page)...but once I remember what the thing is for and re-read it, I generally get the right outcome...(probably not a bad idea to get my brain going)

But I've worked with Javascript and this event and know that the text at the top and the bottom is not specified by the website but by the browser...and that it's the only event that can actually cancel a user navigating away...so there isn't really much else of a solution to actually cancel the navigation event...

Does anyone else have problems interpreting this dialog with the SO text? Could it be re-worded...it's probably just me (apologies in advance)

**edit**
the first answer with a different browser perfectly makes sense to me...i'll just switch browsers perhaps!

Comment: You don't really need to read the text, since it's fixed by the browser and can't be changed. Any time you see this type of dialog, the default button is to leave and the other button is to stay ("cancel" leaving, if that helps)

Comment: Now I'm wondering what's behind the blurred out portion in the upper-right corner. ;)

Comment: @Marcel, looks to me like "answered 28 mi[nutes ago]" along with the top portion of a gravatar.

Comment: @PopularDemand – Ah, that's a feature of Windows, letting the contents below the dialog chrome a bit through; I thought the OP hid a secret text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this when I am editing a post and navigate away [image]

I don't think changing the text could really be an option now as most people are used to it.  Changing it would probably cause even more confusion.

Comment: agreed! whichever browser you're using makes more sense to me than mine (firefox 4)...maybe that's the problem!!!

Comment: I use Chrome hence the nice popup :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you said:

> But I've worked with Javascript and this event and know that the text at the top and the bottom is not specified by the website but by the browser...and that it's the only event that can actually cancel a user navigating away...so there isn't really much else of a solution to actually cancel the navigation event...

We can only control the one sentence and the rest of this ui is dependent on your browser.

Comment: I fully accept that, I think at the time, I thought that the message I was seeing (well how it was presented) was standard...but it's a lot easier to understand in Chrome as @Barry pointed out...so yeah, really it's a browser thing...